# redux-react-session installing package Error

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, npm-install

Terminal Error

```
PS C:\Users\Danial Sama\Downloads\Program Languegs\React Native\danshgah\poroje> npm install redux-react-session
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: poroje@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from redux-react-session@2.6.1
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-react-session
npm ERR!   redux-react-session@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Danial Sama\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Danial Sama\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-18T06_51_08_504Z-debug-0.log
```

This Error showing when i wanted to add redux-react-session package
and don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
npm install redux-react-session --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`